# Automatically shrink an ext4 IMG file

Tags: scripting, ext4, gparted, disk-image

I have an ext4 `img` file containing an Android system partition files.

I mount it by using `sudo mount -t ext4 -o loop,rw system.img system`

When I'm done editing the files and `umount` the file, I notice that the resulting image is significantly larger than the content it has.

I checked with GParted, and it is indeed true : the image file is 2.0Gb, while its partition only has 1.51Gb used (and 506Mb unused).

[image: gparted screenshot]

I can use GParted to resize the partition and shrink the IMG size by 500Mb, but I would like to have it automated, in a script. How could I achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `resize2fs -M system.img` to shrink your *filesystem* to the minimum size.  Note that this does not shrink the *image file* directly.  You would need to use `truncate` to shrink the image file to the new filesystem size (carefully, so you don't chop data off the end).

Comment: **First:** `resize2fs -M system.img` **does** shrink the `ext4` image file, there is no need in `truncate` using. **Second**: `-M` option have [known bug](https://linux.die.net/man/8/resize2fs) which leads to noticeable amount of free space after resizing. **So:** 1) find out what amount of space is really used (for example, with `dh`); 2) use `resize2fs` with specific value.